# How to check if a NSArray has the values of another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have my array `unique` that is my main array and my array `kind`. I need to check that only 1 value of `kind` is present in the array `unique`. Then if there is more than 1 value of the array `kind` in `unique` I need to unset all values but the first one used in the array.

The further i got to achieve this is with the following code but I can not store the `indexpath` of the found object to do a later comparison. xcode says `"bad receiver type nsinteger"`

could anyone help me to achieve this?

```
kind = @[@"#Routine",@"#Exercise",@"#Username"];
    NSMutableArray *uniqueKind = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString* obj in kind) {
        if ( [unique containsObject:obj] ) {
            NSInteger i = [unique indexOfObject:obj];
            [uniqueKind addObject: [i intValue]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be doing what your description says. If all three strings are present in `unique`, you're going to add the indexes of all three to `uniqueKind`. Do you mean that you don't want more than one of _each_ string in `unique`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `NSInteger` is like an `int`, so you can't send it a message (`[i intValue]`). Also, you can't add an `NSInteger` to an array without making it an `NSNumber` or some other object type. You can do it like this:

```
NSInteger i = [unique indexOfObject:obj];
[uniqueKind addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
```

Also (without understanding what you're doing) you might want to use an `NSSet` instead of an array. And you can combine a couple of calls:

```
NSUInteger i = [unique indexOfObject:obj];
if ( i != NSNotFound ) {
    [uniqueKind addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
}
```

Comment: @JoshCaswell Bad copy paste. Thanks for catching it. I was demonstrating that you don't need to do the `containsObject:` call, as `indexOfObject:` will tell you if it's in the array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it would solve your problem, but have you considered using sets (or mutable variation) instead of arrays? They ensure uniqueness and they allow you to check for intersection/containment. See the [NSSet class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSet).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add objects to the NSMutableArray, not the actual intValue. Try converting teh integer to a NSNumber first.

`[uniqueKind addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];`

instead.

(edited )

Comment: Oops - my bad - try converting it to an NSNumber with `numberWithInt: i`